# Linking and compiling shaders for OpenGL 3.3 and 2.1 using LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I am using LWJGL to create an OpenGL context. I can get it running on my machine (OpenGL 4.2 compatible) and with changes to the simple shaders also on OpenGL 2.1.
I have to write code (the shaders, or rather the linking and compilation of them, seem to be the problem here) that is compatible with OpenGL 2.1. I assumed it would be easy to just write:

The Frag shader:

```
#version 120

in vec4 pass_Color;

out vec4 out_Color;

void main(void) {
    out_Color = pass_Color;
}
```

The Vert shader:

```
#version 120

in vec4 in_Position;
in vec4 in_Color;

out vec4 pass_Color;

uniform mat4 Model;
uniform mat4 View;
uniform mat4 Projection;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = Projection * View * Model * in_Position;

    pass_Color = in_Color;
}
```

as the first line of my shaders and call it a day. However, on one machine with a OpenGL 3.3 supporting graphics card, those shaders would not link and compile. When changed to

```
#version 330
// - or even -
#version 150
```

they do link and compile. I have read about compatibility, core and forward compatibility and as I understand it, the problem could be that GLSL 1.20 is not supported on the OpenGL 3.3 machine unless it is instructed in the code to run a compatibility context (I may be phrasing it wrongly, please correct me). But I worry, since 2.1 does not know about OpenGL profiles, surely I will need to do some checks before attempting to setup the context with one.

Even if this is the case, I am not entirely sure how to do the correct logic to ensure that both machines with graphics cards limited to OpenGL 2.1 (and corresponding GLSL version) and machines with much later versions (3.3, 4.2, etc.) will accept it as well (using the LWJGL).

Please note that I would like to keep the code as "modern OpenGL" as possible.

Comment: No machine regardless which version it supports should be compiling those shaders (at least not without some serious compiler warnings). You have told the GLSL compiler to compile it as a GLSL 1.2 shader and then you fed it `in` and `out`, which were not even defined for vertex shader input / output until GLSL 1.3. You need to use `varying` and `attribute`.

Comment: Alright, so I can use different shaders (one using varying and attribute, another using in and out) for each version, would that be the ideal solution then? Checking GL_VERSION and depending on which it is use one or the other?

Comment: Yeah that sounds like it would work.  Have you given it a try?  Also, throughout development, you'll have to be wary about using features that one version supports and another doesn't.  Could lead to a lot of conditional compilations in your shaders.

Comment: I have tried it on my own machine but I do not have access to the OpenGL 2.1 machines at the moment. Is there a way to simulate a OpenGL 2.1 graphics card (so that it would give error if I used 2.1 incompatible versions) with a 4.2 supporting card? If nothing else, I will return to this when I get to test it out in the following week.

Also, thanks for the reminder about the features, Jarrett.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying ogl version like this:

```
        PixelFormat pixelFormat = new PixelFormat();
        ContextAttribs contextAtrributes = new ContextAttribs(3, 2)
            .withForwardCompatible(true)
            .withProfileCore(true);

        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        Display.setTitle(WINDOW_TITLE);
        Display.create(pixelFormat, contextAtrributes);
```

> ...since macs by default support a maximum version of OpenGL 2.1. On OS X 10.7+ you can specifically request the core profile which will give you access to OpenGL 3.2 however unlike Windows and Linux you can't mix OpenGL 3+ features in the standard OpenGL profile.

From [here](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/issues/25).