# GLSL Unsupported Version

Tags: java, macos, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to compile GLSL shaders for use in LWJGL with OpenGL. I'm on macOS Sierra.

I get the following error when trying to compile the shaders:

```
ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '400' is not supported
ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error: #version
```

The shader code works on Windows, but when testing on macOS it doesn't.
Here's the shader code:

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;

out vec2 pass_textureCoords;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;
}
```

Here is how i'm loading the shader...

```
    private static int loadShader(String file, int type) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    ShaderProgram.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("shaders/" + file))
            )) {

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                shaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
            }

            System.out.println(shaderSource.toString());

            int shaderID = GL20.glCreateShader(type);

            GL20.glShaderSource(shaderID, shaderSource);
            GL20.glCompileShader(shaderID);

            if (GL20.glGetShaderi(shaderID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
                System.out.println(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, 500));
                System.err.println("Error compiling shader " + file);
                System.exit(-1);
            }

            return shaderID;
        }
    }
```

The print statement returns the correct output, yet it still gives me the error.

I've searched all over stackoverflow for a solution, yet everyone says that they're compiling it without line breaks, which i have. I'm confused as to why this is occurring.

Comment: Why do people always think that reading files line-by-line is a good way to read files? There are [easier ways.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/326440/734069)

Comment: @NicolBolas Well i mean that doesn't help the question at hand, however Files.readAllBytes (performance wise) is no different to reading line by line, it's only really shorter to write it out.

Comment: what's the value of `glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)` (or equivalent in JWJGL)? Maybe the context just doesn't support GLSL 4.0?

Comment: @Erouax: The problem is that reading line by line has a terrible performance. The string will be reallocated and copied everytime append is called.

Comment: @Erouax: if you're not explicitely creating a forward-compatible core profile context, you will be limited to GL2.1 / GLSL1.20 on OSX.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito It prints 1.20, i tried using #version 120 but it still gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello not an java expert here, i did some experiments using JOGL, so maybe i cant give you a hint to work in the right direction.

An issue with new line on MAC
[How to append a newline to StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534767/how-to-append-a-newline-to-stringbuilder)

Second:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.00.pdf

> The #version directive must occur in a shader before anything else, except for comments and white space.

This is what is looks like RAW in JOGL you see the newline is needed is after the version directive , everthing else has an semicolons as statement separators.

```
  // 
  // create fragment Shader
  int fragShader = gl4.glCreateShader(GL4.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  gl4.glShaderSource(fragShader, 1, 
    new String[]{"#version 420 \n"
    +"out vec4 fragColor;"
    +"void main(void) {"
    +"fragColor = vec4(0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0);}" }, null);
    gl4.glCompileShader(fragShader);
```

Comment: JOGL and the library used by the original poster might handle the shader source code a very little bit differently.

Comment: at least its OpenGL :)

Comment: Yes but as far as I remember, there is a difference between them in handling the termination character '\0', I had to take care of that when I resurrected the JOGL backend of LibGDX.

Comment: I read this few days later and now i think he had to set the forward compatible mode for mac:  

OpenGL:  
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

Java:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870053/linking-and-compiling-shaders-for-opengl-3-3-and-2-1-using-lwjgl

Answer (score 1):

If the other answer doesn't solve the problem for you, I suspect you're creating an OpenGL context with the wrong OpenGL version. You will need to [create a context with the Core Profile](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/UpdatinganApplicationtoSupportOpenGL3/UpdatinganApplicationtoSupportOpenGL3.html) - this also means that legacy functions and features are *not* supported, so if you've used any of those, you'll need to replace them with newer equivalents. (The core profile is not backwards-compatible.)